# ZEND PreDispatch function equivalente in Symfony

Tags: symfony, zend-framework

i want to know the equivalente of preDispatch ZEND function in symfony framework
i need to call this method before the execution of any action in my controller

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [event subscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html#before-filters-with-the-kernel-controller-event), subscribed to `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents::CONTROLLER`.

[More info](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher) about events and event listeners in Symfony